Обновление ядра Люникс Дебиан
Всем привет. В последнее время на виртуальных машинах "веду" (актуализирую) три версии Люникс-дистров: Manjaro, ArchLinux, Debian. К первым двум дистрам вопросов нет. На момент написания этого сообщения они имеют стабильные ядра версии 6.11. И только мой Дебиан имеет версию ядра 6.1. Я с этим дистром работаю недавно. И вполне как-то был уверен, что выполняемые мною команды не только обновят все версии пакетов, но и обновят ядро!
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude full-upgrade

Но что-то я не вижу прогресса. Разъясните, пожалуйста, что не так с обновлением ядра Дебиан. Где я недочитал и недопонял? И как нужно делать правильно?

6.1 это и есть самая свежая версия ядра для актуальной версии дебиана

Секунду! А почему для других дистров на 10 минорных версий больше?

Потому что они, в отличие от дебиана, плевать хотели на Стабильность™

Ну а вообще можно подключить bookworm-backports и установить оттуда ядро 6.11, но стоит иметь в виду, что это потенциально может снизить Стабильность™

Эммм ... хорошо. Твой совет - остальные мои дистры "откатить" на 6.1, или как? Ну чтобы соблюдалась  "стабильность".

Нет, действительно "новые фичи" меня мало волнуют, если что.

Попытка откатить rolling-release дистрибутивы приведёт к ещё большей поломке Стабильности™ и получению лучей ненависти от их сообществ

Спасибо. Я понял. Каждый дистр должен сам определять нужную версию последнего стабильного ядра. Всё верно?

Типа того, арч стремится поставлять самые свежие версии всего, а дебиан больше про «работает — не трогай» (ну или можно установить testing или sid версию дебиана и будет почти как арч, но опять же стоит иметь в виду риски для Стабильности™)

andreymal,  большое тебе спасибо за понятные ответы! Если тебе не составит труда - оформи ответ на мой вопрос в виде ответа, а не комментария. Я его отмечу принятым. Да и сообщество SO "обогатится" еще одним кусочком знаний.

Ядро 6.11 включено в ветвь testing. Следующим летом testing выпустят как новую версию Debian aka trixie.
